# Adobe AEM relative links

Tags: aem

How do you do relative links within text editor component? Adobe AEM doesn't like when I use relative links to external pages by default. It strips them out and shows the broken link symbol.

Comment: Can you provide more info, like example of what link you write and what hierarchy is (path of page which has this link, and page path it points to)?

Comment: Related link for external pages? How it can be possible? If its an external page, then you always need to add domain in your link or am i missing something?

Answer (score 5):

I strongly recommend you to uncheck **Disable Checking** in *Day CQ Link Checker Transformer*.
Be aware that It's your responsibility to ensure all links are valid:
***Completly disable all link checking. All links are handled as valid.***

This is something you want to check with your team (Devs, TAs...). It may work on your local environment and it will fail in QA, UAT and PROD as this option is not checked.
Disabling the link checker might not be a good idea as Content Authors may add broken links, which It'll break user navigation throughout the site if this is not picked during testing and regression testing.
Regarding paths, relative paths are those within the environment you're in. For instance,
`/content/dam/geometrixx/banners/banner-mono.png`
is a relative path, however path to Stack Overflow is outside you environment therefore is external. In order to be valid, you need to provide the full URL including the scheme, either **http**, **https**, **ftp**, **ftps** and so on. A valid external URL would be:
`http://www.stackoverflow.com`
More info about URLs can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

---

Answer (score 1):

While disabling the link checker will work, I'm not sure how you are referencing external websites by relative link.  Relative links are on the same domain by their nature.  Can you give us an example of what you mean?

The other problem with disabling the link checker is that the production deployment will likely have the link checker turned on.  In this case your code will break again.  You probably don't want your client/boss/whatever upset about that.

Relative links can be made to work just fine with the linkchecker.  Can you post some example links?  I can help you make things work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is quite common, if you have URL's (paths) in your domain that are NOT served by AEM. This can be files directly served by the Apache (e.g. robots.txt), Servlets creating dynamic redirects (e.g. language switcher) or another application (e.g. web shop under /shop).

First solution is to mark an individual link for the link checker as valid. Therefore you can add the following attribute to the link tag.

- **`x-cq-linkchecker="valid"`**  - link is marked as valid, without any
  check
- **`x-cq-linkchecker="skip"`**- link is ignored by the link
  checker, and remains as is

e.g. `<a href="/shop/basket" x-cq-linkchecker="valid">Shopping Basket</a>`

Second solution is to configure special-threated link patterns in the OSGi config of the “Day CQ Link Checker Service”. In case you have a second application in the same domain, then you can specify regex-patterns matching the links to this second application. User either “Link Check Override Patterns” (not checked, but rewritten) or “Special Link Patterns” (not checked and not rewritten).

**Example configuration** that only links to `/content/*` are verified. Links that not matching `^/content/.*$` are threated as valid:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
         jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
         service.special_link_prefix="[javascript:,data:,mailto:,#,&lt;!--,${,tel:]"
         service.check_override_patterns="[^system/,^(?!/content/).*$]"
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed my issue in /system/console/configMgr# > Day CQ Link Checker Transformer > Check "Disable Checking" box.

Relative paths now work.

Comment: This isn't a solution. You are just disabling a working validation which conflicts with your problem. Unless I am mistaken, external links (links to other domains) can never be relative.